# Why does the wifi icon not appear on the taskbar in Lubuntu 14?

Tags: lubuntu

I have just updated to Lubuntu 14 from version 13. I now cannot see the wifi icon on the task bar. Is it meant to be there? If so, how can I make it appear?

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, run `nm-applet` . See if it shows icon or raises any error message.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question when I did a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04.  Go to Menu->Preferences->Default applications for LXSessions.  Navigate to Core Applications and then to Network GUI.  Type in nm-applet and then hit reload.

Comment: Worked on my Lubuntu 14.04 ttyl, kudos for clear instructions

Comment: Thanks. The likely responsible (and supposedly fixed) bug is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1308348).

Answer (score 0):

Add the nm-applet into the autostart menu of lxsession as manual autostart application has worked at my computer.
Only check in the preferences menu has not worked.